# VS Extension can't load Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have a Visual Studio extension that we use internally that I'm in the process of updating for Visual Studio 2022. The extension worked fine in previous versions of Visual Studio, but I've had to follow several steps to get it building and running for VS 2022. I've gotten to the point where it will build and run, but I'm getting an error at run time when I'm trying to create a TFS ticket in the extension (which is the main point of the extension).

On this line:

```
projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, cred);
```

I get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
> HResult=0x80070002
> Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> Source=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client

Searching around a bit, it seems that there is a version of that assembly at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`, but apparently you aren't allowed to add that to your project. Because when you try, Visual Studio will complain that:

> A reference to 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common' could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.

Further searching reveals that that assembly is also included with the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client` Nuget package (that I did have referenced in the original version of this extension but it was since removed somewhere along the line), but installing that did not fix the problem either (not with the version that used to work in previous versions of VS, or with the latest version available on NuGet)

I suspect that the problem is that there is a version of this assembly that is loaded by Visual Studio itself and is conflicting with the version that the extension is built again. But trying to add a `bindingRedirect` to `app.config` hasn't worked for me either (although maybe I don't have the version I'm redirecting to correct?).

Does anybody know the correct way to resolve this conflict?